# Reading material for Kalman filter

Tags: reference-request, kalman-filter

Is there a good reading material for Kalman filter? I am referring to ssarkka, but I am facing difficulty in understanding.

Comment: The question is a little vague. You want to understand the theory, application, code? Are you familiar with linear systems, LQR, Gauss Markov models?

Comment: I want to understand the theory. I am familiar with linear systems and Markov models.

Comment: What specifically are you having difficulty with?

Comment: This is a nice overview: https://stanford.edu/class/ee363/lectures/kf.pdf

Comment: For instance ,$p(y_{0:t} )= p(y_{0:t-1},y_t)$ .Is this a way to just divide the joint distribution into two?Why is it required to write in this form?